# Django test using Selenium package error

Tags: python, django, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I want to create some Django test using Selenium package.

Here below is the simple test :

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver

class TestSignup(unittest.TestCase):

def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

def test_signup_fire(self):
    self.driver.get("http://localhost:8000/add/")
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_title').send_keys("test title")
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('id_body').send_keys("test body")
    self.driver.find_element_by_id('submit').click()
    self.assertIn("http://localhost:8000/", self.driver.current_url)

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

but I take this error :

```
TypeError: environment can only contain strings
```

in this line :

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

and I don't know why, any idea how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

As you are seeing the error as :

```
TypeError: environment can only contain strings
```

In the line :

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

This essentially means there is some configuration error while updating the path within **Environment Variables**. To suppress that you can supply the argument with `geckodriver` binary location as follows :

```
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\geckodriver.exe')
```

Comment: is the some error o don't need update `TypeError: environment can only contain strings`